# 10.04 > 10.10 upgrade and the splash screen hangs

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade, nvidia

I have a computer that once I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 the splash screen hangs. I had this issue on another machine that I simply boot into recovery mode and reinstalled the nvidia drivers (both have nvidia cards).

The thing is, on the machine I'm presently having issues with, when I select recovery mode, the monitor tells me "No Signal"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is a friend's laptop needed for University.

Comment: Does Live-CD work?

Comment: What graphics card does this machine have? Can you press (ctrl+)alt+f2 and get a text bootup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can try booting up without Plymouth (the splash screen) by editing grub on boot up. To do so:

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> on startup to access the GRUB menu.
2. Press any key (besides <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to stop the timer. Then select the menu entry (normally the newest) by using the arrow keys.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> at the desired item to go into edit mode.
4. Go to the second from last line (by using the arrow keys). It should say something like: `linux /boot/vmlinux-2.6.31-9 root=UUID=904b4c85-9857 ro quiet splash` (it will **not** be exactly the same).
5. Remove the `quiet splash` options from the line, so it ends in `ro`.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot. Hopefully it will work!